# Select video from video library in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to objective c and ios development
I want to select a video from video library of iphone.
i can chhose images using UIImageview
Is there any possibility to do this

Answer (score 5):

u have to use UIImagePickerController

below tutorial for pick up image

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

where u have to specify mediaTypes of UIImagePickerControllerObject to get video

Check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes) and choose what type you need.

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

Comment: Thank you AppleVijay. If somebody want to know, adding kUTTypeImage show the images too :).

Answer (score 4):

You can't choose images using UIImageView, that is for displaying images. You can easily use UIImagePickerController to choose images; to use it to choose videos instead, just assign an array containing kUTTypeMovie to the picker's `mediaTypes` property:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

It's also possible (in iOS 4.0 and above) to access the library at a lower level, using [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you're asking how you can display thumbnails of videos in your own interface (and you're targeting iOS 4.0 or above), look into [AVAssetImageGenerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to generate the thumbnails and then display them as you would any image. If you're asking how to play a movie, look into [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

This topic may be too old. But I think there's a link that may help others who seek for a similar solution (for example, me).
It use storyboard as well as new framework features introduced in iOS5 and above (ALAssetsLibrary, AVFoundation ...). Here it is [How to Play, Record, and Edit Videos in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

Hope this help.